# Is it possible to have an alias name for a TikZ shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bookcover

I would like to be able to have an alias for a `TikZ' shape or rename the existing one.

The `bookcover` package used to define a `(current trimmed part)' shape to position elements on the specific book cover part (front, back, spine, flaps, ...) that was defining.

With version `3.0`, this shape is renamed to `(trimmed part)`. I have a lot of code using this package and I would like to convert to the new version.

Something that can easy the jobs would be to be able to alias the shape. I couldn't find a way to do it in the TikZ manual. It is possible to alias a node with  `\pgfnodealias`, but it fails when trying to alias `(trimmed part.north west)` and similar nodes.

Comment: Please add a minimal example that shows exactly what you have tried. But the answer is that you can use aliases. If the node is set inside a macro so that you can not directly add it, you can use tricks like `\begingroup\tikzset{nodes={alias=fluffy}}\macro\endgroup`.

Comment: The maintainer of `bookcover` says the next version (3.2) will fix this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{bookcover}
\makeatletter
\def\bookcover@tikz@content#1{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,yshift=-\bookcover@partheight@]
    \begin{scope}[transparent,line width=0pt]
        \pgfset{minimum width=\bookcover@partwidth@,minimum height=\bookcover@partheight@}
        \pgfnode{rectangle}{south west}{}{part}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
        \pgfset{minimum width=\bookcover@partwidth@-\bookcover@tikz@trimmed@part@width@minus,
                minimum height=\bookcover@partheight@-\bookcover@tikz@trimmed@part@height@minus}
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bookcover@tikz@trimmed@part@push@right}
                                    {\bookcover@tikz@trimmed@part@push@up}}
        \pgfnode{rectangle}{south west}{}{trimmed part}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
        \pgfnodealias{current trimmed part}{trimmed part}
        \pgfnodealias{current part}{part}
    \end{scope}
    #1
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewbookcovercomponenttype{tikz}{\bookcover@tikz@content{#1}}
\renewbookcovercomponenttype{tikz clip}{\bookcover@tikz@content{\clip (part.south west) rectangle (part.north east);#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{bg whole}{
    \fill[black] (current part.south west) rectangle (current part.north east);
    \fill[gray] (current trimmed part.south east) rectangle (current trimmed part.north west);}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The maintainer of `bookcover` says the next version (3.2) will fix this bug!

Comment: Sorry, I have been out of computer. I wouldn't call it a bug. Just a design decision that is not back compatible

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already accepted.

Comment: Thank you. Version 3.2 has been released which is fixed this problem.

Comment: Thank for the comment. I did not check yet the upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm --- just to show you *why* you need to post an example... this:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw, fill=yellow](A){I am A};
    \draw (A.north) -- ++(0,1);
    \pgfnodealias{B}{A}
    \draw [red] (B.south) -- ++(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does work:

[image]

Comment: Another reason why it may not work is that the OP tried to use an alias for a node anchor, or that some `remember picture` is missing: `\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[circle, draw, fill=yellow](A){I am A};
    \draw (A.north) -- ++(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \pgfnodealias{B}{A}
    \draw [red] (B.south) -- ++(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` drop `remember picture` in the second picture and it won't work. As you say, an example is needed.